# How to run background coding by selecting data shown in the listview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to use list view for dynamic display of data from database. I want that on clicking that data a background coding should run by getting the ID of the selected data and then it should navigate to another page.

Comment: What have you tried so far. Show your code. This site really isn't a place where people do your work for you. We will answer questions however.

Comment: sounds interesting and what are your thoughts. What will be there in the background coding will it be someting related to the another page? then where you keep the processed data? Even if you keep will it be useful. You can take benefit of process or http-handler.

Comment: I know this portal is for help only I tried almost every effort to work on my problem I am just asking for any help as i am stuck here. On selecting the data in listview its ID should get selected and passed on another page so i can show full information.

Comment: :) The only thing you want to get the id of the selected data. Its simple. Fetch the id from the database I think you might be and use it in the query string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer which worked for me

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID" 
        onselectedindexchanging="ListView1_SelectedIndexChanging">
<LayoutTemplate>
    <ul>
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />    
    </ul>                
</LayoutTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
    <li>
        <%#Eval("Subject") %>
         <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkSelect" Text="Read More" CommandName="Select"     runat="server" />
    </li>
</ItemTemplate>
<SelectedItemTemplate>
       <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkSelect" Text="Read More" CommandName="Select" runat="server"
           ForeColor="White" />
           <%#Eval("Subject") %>
           </SelectedItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
```

The .CS file

```
protected void ListView1_SelectedIndexChanging(object sender, ListViewSelectEventArgs e)
    {
        ListView1.SelectedIndex = e.NewSelectedIndex;
        string pid = ListView1.SelectedDataKey.Value.ToString();
        Session["id"] = pid;
        Response.Redirect("About.aspx");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ListView `CommandArgument` Property in aspx and ListView  `OnItemCommand` on code behind like this

in short you can get ID in `OnItemCommand` like and navigate to another page like this :

```
string employeeID = EmployeesListView.DataKeys[dataItem.DisplayIndex].Value.ToString();
Response.redirect("~/index.aspx?employeeID="+employeeID);
```

**Page Source (aspx)**

```
  <asp:ListView runat="server" 
    ID="EmployeesListView"
    OnItemCommand="EmployeesListView_OnItemCommand"
    DataSourceID="EmployeesDataSource" 
    DataKeyNames="EmployeeID">
    <LayoutTemplate>
      <table runat="server" id="tblEmployees" 
             cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" width="440px" border="1">
        <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></tr>
      </table>
      <asp:DataPager ID="EmployeesDataPager" runat="server" PageSize="10">
        <Fields>
          <asp:NumericPagerField />
        </Fields>
      </asp:DataPager>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
      <tr runat="server">
        <td>
          <asp:Label runat="server" ID="NameLabel" 
            Text='<%#Eval("LastName") + ", " + Eval("FirstName") %>' />
        </td>
        <td style="width:80px">
          <asp:LinkButton runat="server" 
            ID="SelectEmployeeButton" 
            Text="Add To List" 
            CommandName="AddToList" 
            CommandArgument='<%#Eval("LastName") + ", " + Eval("FirstName") %>' />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:ListView>
```

**Code behind (.cs)**

```
  protected void EmployeesListView_OnItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
  {
    if (String.Equals(e.CommandName, "AddToList"))
    {
      // Verify that the employee ID is not already in the list. If not, add the
      // employee to the list.
      ListViewDataItem dataItem = (ListViewDataItem)e.Item;
      string employeeID = 
        EmployeesListView.DataKeys[dataItem.DisplayIndex].Value.ToString();

      if (SelectedEmployeesListBox.Items.FindByValue(employeeID) == null)
      {
        ListItem item = new ListItem(e.CommandArgument.ToString(), employeeID);
        SelectedEmployeesListBox.Items.Add(item);
      }
    }
  }
```

Here is the [Reference site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.itemcommand.aspx).